# Testing Location Aware iPhone App

Tags: ios4, mapkit

I am trying to build a jogging app which will plot the user's jogging route. My question is that how do I test that app. Since the app depends on the user's location and the location should be changing in order for me to plot a line or something where the user is jogging. If I just move around in my house the CLLocation might not give me any new points. What is the preferred way of testing location aware apps?

Comment: For what it's worth, it's possible to get location from a mobile app (e.g. a normal website) for iOS devices via HTML5 Geolocation API <http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html>.  You could use this to derive testing data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all under NDA, so I'll be very vague.

You should check out Xcode 4.2 that is presently in Developer preview along with iOS 5.

You need to be a registered iPhone developer to access this build of Xcode.